# Good way to pass many variables to function?

Tags: matlab, arguments, octave

When one has a function, which needs many specific variables when called, what is a good way, to pass them?

Should one always pass all variable explicitly? How about storing them in structs (or objects)? But somehow I think, this makes things a bit obscure, as these structs/objects have to be well defined to make sure, they have all the fields, when handed in to the function in question.

Also probably local variables are accessed most quickly, whereas adressing struct fields might be slow in a loop...

Or is it a good thing to run an external script where everything is defined global (but even in this case on has to make everything available to the function using the `global` keyword)

Comment: @usar Sorry, you're right. Looks like this question is better asked at CodeReview. I'll try there...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to pass many variables to a function, is to use [varargin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html). Use it together with nargin.

```
function varlist2(X,Y,varargin)
   fprintf('Total number of inputs = %d\n',nargin);

   nVarargs = length(varargin);
   fprintf('Inputs in varargin(%d):\n',nVarargs)
   for k = 1:nVarargs
      fprintf('   %d\n', varargin{k})
end
```

Varargin can also be used for optional variables.. So it gives a lot of options...